# Why Heroku doesn't allow me to upload my webpage?

Tags: reactjs, database, heroku, upload, local

I'm trying to upload to Heroku the webpage we're working on in order to be able to use the information we're creating locally. I follow all the steps, but when I accept the last command, this error appears. I tried to do all the steps again but the error remains.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Recently Heroku stopped free web hosting. You can try vercel to deploy your website.